# How to programmatically open "Access Point Names" screen in Android?

Tags: android

How to open that page?
Wireless & Networks -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names

Please provide the sample code for this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you need that, please hire a consultant. You should be able to find this by searching this site or checking Android SDK documentation. Once you have some code, if you need help with it you can post the code here and explain the problem you're having, and someone here can probably help you. We do expect you to put some effort into solving  the issue yourself first, though. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.ApnSettings");
startActivity(intent);
```